clipping of objects when zooming out
I've been trying to model this simple street, the geometry (I think) looks fine. But when I start to zoom out, artefacts and clipping begins to appear even though the geometry looks simple and nothing is intercepting with one another.



It would have been helpful if you had posted screenshots of the viewport's clip settings and maybe the camera's as well. I would suspect the Clip End value is way too high.
